# How can I save a text block in visual mode to a file in Vim?

Tags: file, vim, save, selection

The title is very descriptive. Just in case, I will give an example:

```
START BLOCK1
something
END BLOCK1

START BLOCK2
something
somenthing...
END BLOCK2
```

1. I select the `BLOCK1` in visual mode
2. I yank it by pressing <kbd>y</kbd>
3. How can I save the yanked `BLOCK1` to some other file?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Select the text you wish to save, in either line visual or block visual mode, and

```
:w new.txt
```

That's what you type, but you won't actually *see* exactly what's above. When you press `:`, you'll go to the command line which will automatically get filled in with selection information. It'll look something like this:

```
:'<,'>
```

Just carry on typing the rest (`w new.txt`) to get

```
:'<,'>w new.txt
```

...and press enter.

Comment: That doesn't provide the expected result as it only writes full lines, disregarding the selection start and end position inside the line. Any solution for that?  Otherwise I like to file the main question again.

Comment: @dronus - I don't quite understand what you're asking. This does what the OP asked, to the best of my understanding the question.

Comment: If you select in any non-line visual mode, `:w` still writes out full lines touched by the selected range, but not the exact range beginning or ending inside of lines. For example, if you select a narrow column in block select mode, or a part of one line in visual select mode, the full line will be written by `:w`, even if `y`would copy the correct parts of the line.

Comment: @dronus - Ah, okey. Yes, that's correct. But still, while I can't talk for others, what it does is *expected* behaviour for me.

Answer (score 18):

With the block is selected, you can `:'<,'>w other-file`, which will write only the selected block to `other-file`.  Hitting `:` in visual mode should place `'<,'>` into the command line for you already, so you really only have to type `:w other-file`.

Comment: Vim always selects whole lines for piping to external command, so you can use the unix/cygwin 'cut' command to select rectangle of column N to M, of each line in the selection: `:'<,'>w !cut -cN-M > new.txt`. Surprised that highest voted answer and readers don't seem to understand the question.

Comment: @mosh but when the selected text is not aligned to a column, this would not work either.

Answer (score 7):

There's probably a simpler way to do this, but what I would do is create a new buffer (or tab) and then paste it in with `p`.  You can create a new buffer with `:new` or a new tab with `:tabnew`.  You can write the buffer/tab to a file as normal with `:w filename`.

Comment: Be sure to delete the extra line at the top!! (Pasting into an empty buffer creates an extra line at the top, or if using `P`, at the bottom.)

Answer (score 3):

Like @dronus mentioned in the comments, the `:w !pbcopy` suggestions does not copy correctly because it copies the entire line. If I want to copy only the url in a line, I will not be able to. Here's a line that you can add to your `.vimrc` file so that everytime you hit CTRL-C, the selected line in your vim will be copied to clipboard:

```
map <C-c> y:e ~/clipsongzboard<CR>P:w !pbcopy<CR><CR>:bdelete!<CR>
```

If you'd like to read details about what this does, you can read about this on [my blog](http://vimtips.quora.com/How-to-Copy-to-clipboard-on-vim)

Its the same implementation as what @rmeador suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @songz's solution, I prefer do it like this using ":new"

```
vmap <C-c> y:new ~/.vimbuf<CR>VGp:x<CR>:!pbcopy < ~/.vimbuf<CR><CR>
```

Comment: pbcopy is, to my knowledge, only present on OSX. There are similar programs on Linux and other systems but they go by different names and work differently.

Comment: Yep, it works only if pbcopy executable :)
So no harm at all

Answer (score 2):

### Vim get the visual selection and save to a file:

```
    function! Get_visual_selection()
        "get the position of left start visual selection
        let [line_start, column_start] = getpos("'<")[1:2]
        "get the position of right end visual selection
        let [line_end, column_end] = getpos("'>")[1:2]
        "gotta catch them all.
        let lines = getline(line_start, line_end)
        if len(lines) == 0
            return ''
        endif
        "edge cases and cleanup.
        let lines[-1] = lines[-1][: column_end - 2]
        let lines[0] = lines[0][column_start - 1:]
        return join(lines, "\n")
    endfunction

    function Save_visually_selected_text_to_file()
        let selected_text = Get_visual_selection()
        call writefile(split(selected_text, "\n"), "/tmp/something.txt")
    endfunction

    "the c-u does a union of all lines in visual selection.
    "this goes in the vimrc
    vnoremap <F10> :<c-u>call Save_visually_selected_text_to_file()<cr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basing on @chenkaie's variant, works well for me:

`let mapleader = ","
let g:mapleader = ","
vmap <leader>y y:new ~/.vbuf<CR>VGp:x<CR>
nmap <leader>p :r ~/.vbuf<CR>`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799899/how-can-i-save-a-text-block-in-visual-mode-to-a-file-in-vim/57703752#answer-799933) answer above,

- when using the mouse to select (1),
- and the problem of only copying whole lines mentioned by the comment
  of @dronus to it, when just wanted to partly copy lines (2):

(1) At my Debian based DietPi (Raspberry PI)system, vim acts a little different like in the preferred solution above when using the mouse to enter and select 'VISUAL MODE' on my Ubuntu 16.04 work station. Then

- y to yank it

but if I type ':' for command, it will not show up with the

```
'<,'>
```

where I can just simply add my

```
w new.txt
```

after it. So I just typed it by myself and it did work:

```
'<,'>w new.txt
```

and it copies the whole line(s) yanked content to my file 'new.txt', whereas '<,' seem to mean 'copy selected lines and '>' redirect it to the write command's referenced file.

(2) And to the problem of not pasting part of the line(s), like in @dronus [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799899/how-can-i-save-a-text-block-in-visual-mode-to-a-file-in-vim/57703752#comments-799933) mentioned, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620672/copy-and-paste-content-from-one-file-to-another-file-in-vi#answer-4620693) solution (the selected one, first alternative) worked for me:

Edit the first file, yanking the text you want. Then open your second file from within vi (:e /path/to/other/file) and paste it (by typing p). Save it (like above ':w new.txt'.

It will then just copy the part of the lines marked up by mouse or 'y' with the cursors.

[EDIT] On my Ubuntu system: Sometimes selecting by mouse does NOT enter 'VISUAL MODE' in vim. Then the normal copy/paste can be selected using the context menu... I have not found the reason why Ubuntu changed it behaviour from a 'client acting behaviour' to a 'host' one (withUbuntu hosting the ssh bash window to my 'Client')...