# Copy and paste content from one file to another file in VIM from remote machine

Tags: vim, copy-paste, vi, cut

I have found lots of questions about coping content of a file in `Vim` from one file to another and of course there are various ways to do it ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620672/copy-and-paste-content-from-one-file-to-another-file-in-vi)-[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803436/how-to-copy-paste-text-from-vi-to-different-applications)). I'm working on a remote machine and I'm going to copy large amount of data from a file in Vim to my laptop. None of the methods I have found yet works for coping from a remote machine. I have to use `scp` for any thing that I need from the remote machine. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

> I can't use `"*100yy` to copy content and remote machine does not have
>   any graphical editor. – Abolfazl

Naturally, if the editor has no notion of a GUI or a window system, it cannot use the clipboard, let alone that of your networked laptop. One option is to use the copy function of the local terminal program where you enter `ssh`, but of course that is practically limited by the terminal size.
If your laptop runs Windows, I recommend using `WinSCP` instead of `ssh` and the remote `vim` - you can configure `WinSCP` to edit the remote file with your local `gvim`, with all its features.

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal:

```
$ man ssh
/-X
```

Comment: I didn't get
`bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'`

Comment: `<CR>` is the return/enter key. I'll just remove that.

Comment: when I ssh with -X I can't use "*100yy to copy content and remote machine does not have any graphical editor.