# Copy column from one vi editor to other

Tags: vi

I was trying to yank a column of 1300 lines from one vi editor and paste it on other open vi editor. I could able to paste only 49 lines of a column.

Comment: Are you yanking columns or yanking lines? Do you have two vi sessions open or do you have two files open in different windows within the same vi instance?

Comment: I want to yank column..I have two vi sessions open..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you can yank columns between vim sessions. Your best bet might be two open up both files within one vim session using `:sp` or `:vsp` then you can copy and paste as you normally do within one file

If you wanted to copy lines over, in command mode, you can use: `:r! sed -n <begining line nubmer>,<end line number>p <path to file>`. Where `r!` runs an external command, and `sed` searches for only the lines in the range given.

For more information, check out these sources:
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9644522/3865495