# Selecting text and saving it with keymap

Tags: vim

I've made c# command line program that takes a window handle and a string as parameters.  It brings the window with the handle to the foreground, uses SendKeys to send the string that was passed, and brings the window that was previously at the foreground back to the foreground.

I made this program so that I could send selections of text from vim to any program I want, such as a python interactive.

I could not figure out how to send the selection directly to the program, but I did find out how to save selected text in visual mode([How can I save a text block in visual mode to a file in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799899/how-can-i-save-a-text-block-in-visual-mode-to-a-file-in-vim) - It saves whole lines, but that is okay for my purposes.  Ideally though, it would not save just lines).  So I changed the styring paraeter of my program to a filename.  My plan was that vim would save the selected text to a file, and call the program with the filename.

Here is part of my vimrc

```
let g:send_keys_handle = 0
let g:send_keys_file = $home . "\\vim\\send.txt"
function! SendSelection()
if g:send_keys_handle
silent !cls
let x = "silent !cmdHost " . g:send_keys_handle . " " . "\"" . g:send_keys_file . "\""
echom x
execute x
endif
endfunction
command! SendS call SendSelection()
noremap <F5> <esc>va(a(a(a(a(a(a(a(a(a(a(a(a(a(a(a(:w ~\vim\send.txt<cr>
```

The key mapping is not complete, but vim isn't even executing all of it now.  When I press F5, it selects the topmost parentheses as expected, but it does not save the selection to a file.

The SendS command does work, so that is not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With all those repeated `a(` text objects, you presumably intend to capture the text in the outermost parentheses. Unfortunately, if there are less parens than text objects, Vim will beep and abort the mapping, so the remainder won't be executed.

A possible solution is to split this into two parts, and use `:normal!` for the selection. That will only abort the `:normal` part; the remainder of the mapping will still be executed. You need to re-establish the visual selection with `gv`, though.

```
nnoremap <F5> :execute 'normal! va(a(a(a(a(a(a(a(a(a(a(a(a(a(a(a('<CR>gv:w ~\vim\send.txt<CR>
```

---

An alternative to `:write` (which also emits messages, and sets the *alternate file* unless you prepend `:keepalt`) would be `y`anking of the selection, and use of the lower-level `writefile()` function to store the selection in a file.

Comment: Can you give an example of the alternative?  I don't really understand it (I'm pretty new to vim).